# Node and Express - Asset manager for route-specific resources

Tags: node.js, express, assets

I have found some asset-managers for node and express:

[connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets/),
[bundle-up](https://github.com/Cowboy-coder/bundle-up/),
[node.packer](https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.packer/),
[node-static-asset](https://github.com/bminer/node-static-asset/)

But all of them uses only one config to serve concatenated and minified assets in production. Does anyone know how to manage route-specific resources with asset managers?

Say that I want to have:

on '/route1' JS files 'one.js' and 'two.js'

on '/route2' JS files 'three.js' and 'four.js'

Right now I use my own 'asset manager' like this:

```
app.get('/route', function(req, res) {
  res.render('route', {
    title: 'Nice title',
    assets: ['jquery', 'utils', 'minifier'] // file names in JS directory
  });
});
```

But this way JS files are not minified and concatenated on production.

Answer (score 4):

For [bundle-up](https://github.com/Cowboy-coder/bundle-up/), it says you can "namespace" bundles. While it is still using one asset config, won't this technically work? Because then in your route views you can use the specialized render for the specific route namespace.

If you're using a template engine that supports inheritance (e.g. Jade), you can then include this asset reference in a sub-view (in a specific route).

For a Jade template inheritance sample, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1205026).

Comment: I'm the author of bundle-up. Yes, namespaces are perfect for route-specific bundles.